# struts 2 file upload and form data

Tags: file-upload, struts2, form-data, multipartform-data

Action class in struts 2 is model driven to a bean.
In the form submit there are several form data(text field) and the file upload tag. When i try to remove all the filetags and submit then the bean value is populating but if i include the file tags then the form data are not been populated. 
Is it possible to send both multiple file upload and form data to server in a single form submit?

Answer (score 0):

It is working fine problem is actually in firebug resend request. When actual formsubmit it is working fine but while resending the same request it is not working.